# Why don't some applications see my NFS mounted volumes?

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs

I have a workstation running Ubuntu 20.04 and it is configured to mount 4 different NFS volumes that are being exported on my local network from a nearby FreeBSD (server) system.  My /etc/fstab on the Ubuntu (workstation) system is obviously configured properly, and I have been using these NFS-mounted volumes via the workstation for multiple years now.  Mostly I can do all the things to and with files on these NFS volumes that I would expect to be able to do, i.e. I can create, delete, read, and write files on the NFS volumes with no problems.  The NFS volumes are seen by the Ubuntu file manager and I can see the mount points and files within the NFS volumes from the command line.  In short, all is well and as expected EXCEPT that the file chooser dialogs in a couple of different applications just don't even see the NFS volumes and/or their mount points as even existing.  The two specific applications where the built-in file choosers don't even seem to see any of the NFS volumes are (1) gimp and (2) timeline.

Can anyone tell me why these NFS volumes are perfectly accessible EXCEPT from these two specific applications, and how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Are they snaps? If so, beside $HOME they may access resources under /media and /mnt only, and that if the required permissions are enabled. Snaps run confined by default.

Comment: I installed the timeline application as a snap, but I believe that I had installed gimp via "su root; apt install gimp"... but it was a long time ago.  Anyway, is there no way to "un-confine" these applications?

Comment: Just open Ubuntu Software, search and open any software. If a snap and already installed it'll have a "permissions" button. Everything else is self-explanatory. Again, even with additional permission they won't access anything outside of $HOME, /media and /mnt.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you mean by "open Ubuntu software".  Could you please clarify?

Comment: Oops!  I just noticed your additional comment "even with additional permission they won't access anything outside of $HOME, /media and /mnt".  I *really* do not understand this. I mean what's the point of disallowing access to NFS volumes?  Seem crazy and counterproductive to me!